# Alternative to backgroundservice cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a cross platform application and I have some problem with updating a plugin Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService (https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService)

I saw that the developer said there is another plugin more recent : https:// github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core
. But when I install it I have some problem :[see console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf8Pt.png)

Do you have any idea how to solve this ? 
Do I have to update something else ?

Is there any alternative ?

thanks by advance ! 
EDIT : I asked the developer of the plugin (github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/issues/72) and he said it has nothing to do with the plugin

Comment: You need to ask the developer of the plugin.

Comment: Okay I'll do that :) thanks